# Does Spring @Autowired create new instance of parameters for each bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

> **Does Spring create new instances of constructor parameters of the same type for different beans?**

For example, I have two REST controllers:

**First:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/getHwidData")
public class GetHwidDataController {

    private final ApiKeysDatabase apiKeysDb;
    private final BanwareDatabase banwareDb;

    @Autowired
    public GetHwidDataController(ApiKeysDatabase apiKeysDb, BanwareDatabase banwareDb) {
        this.apiKeysDb = apiKeysDb;
        this.banwareDb = banwareDb;
    }
}
```

**Second:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/setHwidData")
public class SetHwidDataController {

    private final ApiKeysDatabase apiKeysDb;
    private final BanwareDatabase banwareDb;

    @Autowired
    public SetHwidDataController(ApiKeysDatabase apiKeysDb, BanwareDatabase banwareDb) {
        this.apiKeysDb = apiKeysDb;
        this.banwareDb = banwareDb;
    }
}
```

As you may see, both controllers' constructors are `@Autowired`, and both accept the same object types: an `ApiKeysDatabase` and a `BanwareDatabase`.

I have some caching and other instance-dependent stuff inside those `*Database` classes, so I'd like to know: when the two above-stated REST controllers are created, **will their `apiKeysDb` and `banwareDb` fields be respectively equal** (hold the same instance of the `ApiKeysDatabase` and `BanwareDatabase` objects respectively)? That is,

```java
GetHwidDataController ctrlOne = ...
SetHwidDataController ctrlTwo = ...

assertTrue ctrlOne.apiKeysDb == ctrlTwo.apiKeysDb 
        && ctrlOne.banwareDb == ctrlTwo.banwareDb
```

Comment: Depends on the bean.  You can annotate each one to have different scopes: prototype, singleton, request, session, global session: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: The caching and instance dependent stuff is a terrible idea.  These should be shared singletons.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of the bean, the default scope is singleton so in that case, no, it is not going to create a new instance but it will use the same one.

You can change the scope of a bean with the `@Scope` annotation.